# Automatic ID and Created/Modified By/Datetime fields?

Tags: mysql, audit

Is it possible to get MySQL to automagically create and manage a record ID, Created By/Datetime and Modified By/Datetime columns for all tables in a database?

Note: Not looking to manually create columns for every table, then either auto-increment for id or set the other 4 via triggers.

Asking if there might be some config or auditing options I'm just not finding that could be applied database-wide, ie would apply to all tables including new ones as they're created?

Haven't touched mysql for > 1 decade (and only a lil bit then), and pretty sure the answer to this question is "it just doesn't work that way and never has", but asking just in case there's some obvious I'm missing because I have this vague memory of it just working like that. Prolly was some other database or app.

Cheers,
:)Benja

Comment: MySQL (and any other DBMS) will never do this. If you need in autoincremented `id` and autoutilized timestamp columns in the table(s) then you must create these columns explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

*It just doesn't work that way and never has. :-)*

It's like asking why doesn't Java automatically make every class include a reference to a log4j object, and log every exception that occurs.

The answer is that not every class needs that, and Java has no business second-guessing the developer's intentions.

Technologies like an RDBMS or a programming language are [horizontal technologies](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/7592/horizontal-application). They must make few assumptions about the intended usage to be usable for the widest variety of applications possible.

In MySQL, you can declare a key column as auto-increment, but in any given database, not every table needs an auto-increment primary key. Some take natural keys, some are references to other tables that have their own auto-increment, and some primary keys are better as some data type other than integers.

For the timestamps, modern MySQL does have improved features for automatic timestamps that update to the current time on INSERT and UPDATE. This used to work only for the TIMESTAMP data type, but now it works for DATETIME too. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html for details. Again, this feature is not necessarily needed in *every* table, so you must define the columns in the tables in which you do need it.

Some application frameworks over the past 20 years have tried to impose a convention that every table should have an integer auto-increment primary key, and every table should have created_at and updated_at timestamp columns. Cf. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

But that's only application developer tools that do that. MySQL has no such convention.